# PHP MongoDB extension shows up on phpinfo() but not on command line?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-extension, php-mongodb

I'm using WAMPserver and trying to get MongoDB working. I have the DLL in the PHP extensions folder and loaded the extension in php.ini. When I go to a pae on localhost with `phpinfo()` it shows that MongoDB is loaded. But when I go to the command line and run `php -m` or `php --re mongodb` it does not show up. I checked to make sure the correct php binary is being loaded by both apache and the environment path.

I need to be sure he extension is visible from the command line so that I can install the mongodb client with composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. Apache was loading a different php.ini file than the one in the php directory. I had edited the apache php.ini file but not the php directory php.ini file. After editing both, problem was resolved.

When accessing php.ini from the WAMPserver toolbar icon, it opens the apache php.ini file.